# Sql Paging result with one selected row on top

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

A bit of context: I have a multi step form, in step1 the user must select a row in a table with pagination (filters + sorts), then he goes to step2 but at any moment he could come back to step1 and need to see the previously selected row.
NB: I dont want to keep the page number in frontend storage because if the table has changed, the selected id may not be on the same page any more

The test db:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_CTE](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
    
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 20 
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    insert into TABLE_CTE values (@i, CONCAT('FirstName', @i), CONCAT('LastName',  @i))
END
```

Sample of current query

```
DECLARE @PagingOffset int = 0;
DECLARE @PagingSize int = 5;
DECLARE @SelectedId int = 20;

WITH CTE_FILTERED AS (
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName
        --+ lot of complex subselect
    FROM TABLE_CTE
    WHERE  1 = 1
        AND FirstName LIKE '%1%'
) 
SELECT 
    --Cant explain why but looks faster than COUNT(*) OVER()
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE_FILTERED) Total
    , CTE_FILTERED.*
FROM CTE_FILTERED
-- Could be ordered by anything
ORDER Id
OFFSET @PagingOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PagingSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Result

```
Total   Id  FirstName   LastName
11  1   FirstName1  LastName1
11  10  FirstName10 LastName10
11  11  FirstName11 LastName11
11  12  FirstName12 LastName12
11  13  FirstName13 LastName13
```

From here i see 3 solutions

1. Query the row id, then query the PagedResult (-1 row) and concact them in backend
2. Find a way to query the page number of the rowId selected then bring the user directly to this page
3. Find a way to keep our selected id on top of all results no matter the paging (filters and sorts) => best scenario in my opinion

I just achieved the solution 3 but it looks really complex, maybe there is a better way to achieve it?

```
DECLARE @PagingOffset int = 0;
DECLARE @PagingSize int = 5;
DECLARE @SelectedId int = 20;

WITH CTE_FILTERED2 AS (
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName
        --+ lot of complex subselect
    FROM TABLE_CTE
    WHERE  1 = 1
        AND (Id = @SelectedId 
            OR FirstName LIKE '%1%')
),
CTE_FILTERED_SELECTED2 AS (
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName
    FROM CTE_FILTERED2
    WHERE CTE_FILTERED2.Id = @SelectedId
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName
    FROM CTE_FILTERED2
    WHERE CTE_FILTERED2.Id != @SelectedId
    -- Could be ordered by anything
    ORDER BY Id
    -- forced to add an offset to be able to sort
    OFFSET @PagingOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PagingSize ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE_FILTERED_SELECTED2) Total
    , CTE_FILTERED_SELECTED2.*
FROM CTE_FILTERED_SELECTED2
-- forced to order by something to be able to use offset
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
OFFSET @PagingOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PagingSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Result

```
Total   Id  FirstName   LastName
12  20  FirstName20 LastName20
12  1   FirstName1  LastName1
12  10  FirstName10 LastName10
12  11  FirstName11 LastName11
12  12  FirstName12 LastName12
```

EDIT Final solution

```
SELECT TOP (@PagingSize) Priority, Id, FirstName, LastName, Total
FROM 
( 
  SELECT Priority = 1, Id, FirstName, LastName, -1 Total
   FROM dbo.TABLE_CTE WHERE Id = @SelectedId
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Priority = 2, Id, FirstName, LastName, Total
   FROM 
   (
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*) OVER () + IIF(@SelectedId IS NULL, 0, 1) Total
      FROM dbo.TABLE_CTE
      WHERE FirstName LIKE '%1%'
      ORDER BY Id
    OFFSET @PagingOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PagingSize ROWS ONLY
   ) AS y
   WHERE Id != @SelectedId
) AS z
ORDER BY Priority;

Priority    Id  FirstName   LastName    Total
1   20  FirstName20 LastName20  -1
2   1   FirstName1  LastName1   12
2   10  FirstName10 LastName10  12
2   11  FirstName11 LastName11  12
2   12  FirstName12 LastName12  12
```

Comment: `Id` is a key, right? Why don't you want to keep that in a session variable on the front end? Whether the actual value is 15 or 15 million doesn't really matter, it's still the same number of bytes. I'm not quite sure I understand the goal but it seems like your question is complicated by multiple things that aren't relevant (like forcing a nonsensical order to use OFFSET or the user's workflow). Could you simplify a bit?

Comment: Also the `ORDER BY ... CASE` expression that uses an int or a string [could be problematic](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by).

Comment: yes Id is the primary key, but depending on user filters/sorts/paging size im not sure in wich page the this id would be when it comes back on the form page.

i removed some order by but i need to keep at least one as offset required order by and order by request top or offset ^^'

Comment: @MatBailie exactly sorry for my English ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a little simpler (but I didn't want to complicate it with retrieving counts). Basically you assign a priority to the *selected* row, and assign everything else a lower priority, then you can sort on that artificial column.

```
DECLARE @PagingOffset  int = 0,
        @PagingSize    int = 5,
        @SortId        bit = 1,
        @SortFirstName bit = 0,
        @SortLastName  bit = 0,
        @SelectedId    int = 20;

SELECT TOP (@PagingSize) Id, FirstName, LastName
FROM 
( 
  SELECT Priority = 1, Id, FirstName, LastName
   FROM dbo.TABLE_CTE WHERE Id = @SelectedId
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Priority = 2, Id, FirstName, LastName
   FROM 
   (
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName
      FROM dbo.TABLE_CTE
      WHERE FirstName LIKE '%1%'
      -- AND Id <> @SelectedId
      ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @SortId = 1        THEN Id END,
        CASE WHEN @SortFirstName = 1 THEN FirstName END,
        CASE WHEN @SortLastName = 1  THEN LastName END
        OFFSET @PagingOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PagingSize ROWS ONLY
   ) AS y
) AS z
ORDER BY Priority;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b50cf63ec61028c546756862996b07fa)

The outer ordering matches what you wrote (`SELECT NULL` = `don't care`) but you could easily repeat the case expression on the outer:

```
ORDER BY Priority,
        CASE WHEN @SortId = 1        THEN Id END,
        CASE WHEN @SortFirstName = 1 THEN FirstName END,
        CASE WHEN @SortLastName = 1  THEN LastName END;
```

Comment: greaaat, after reading you article i will also move the "order by case" in my backend code to generate the "order by" part dynamically, many thx

Comment: Could you tell me how would you retrieve the total ? ^^'

Comment: Note: This can lead to the row with `id = @SelectedId` appearing in the results twice; once for Priority1 and once for Priority2.  If that's intended/desired, I'd suggest that this should be two result sets and the 'selected item' and the 'paged list' should be displayed separately to the user.  That said, I'm still very unclear on exactly what really is required here, and why.

Comment: @MatBailie That's an easy filter to add. The thrust was simplification, I didn't want to make it more complicated by having filters, adding counts, converting to dynamic SQL, etc.

Comment: Of course I added a 'AND Id != @SelectedId'  to avoid this case :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have aribtrary filters and arbitrary sorting, and want to guarantee your users always see the page with an arbitrary row in it...

```
DECLARE @PagingSize int = 5;
DECLARE @SelectedId int = 20;

WITH
  filtered_sorted_paged AS
(
  SELECT
    <anything>,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <anything>) - 1) / @PagingSize + 1  AS page_id
  FROM
    <anything>
  WHERE
    <anything>
),
  page_search AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(CASE WHEN id = @SelectedId THEN page_id END) OVER ()  AS selected_page_id
  FROM
    filtered_sorted_paged
)
SELECT
  <stuff>
FROM
  page_search
WHERE
  page_id = selected_page_id
```

For large datasets repeating this for every user action seems expensive, but it appears to do what you ask...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f3e90f195bc4e3dbcd03b4e194d94d4e

Comment: filters and sorts can be changed by users, same for selectedId so this doesnt working.
Worst case users selected id=20 but then apply a filter id=1 and must see the id=20 + the id=1, it may be to tricky to handle it properly on sql side. i could just force a filter from frontend when there is a previously id selected

Comment: @Sayroyten - The user can apply filters that exclude the selected row, but you want that row to be included anyway?  I'm starting to wonder why you are trying to display the 'selected item' and the 'paged list' together?  Why no just display them separately?  *(Filtering to include emails with a `1` and then inclduing a row that **doesn't** match that, seems, umm, contrived.)*  Try this... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6eddf286541eddfb4d51d8645d25a523

Comment: just because i like complex stuff xD and to save some space on the user front end page. Anyway i got a solution, thx for ur help